# Create NTFS report and show whether user accounts are enabled or disabled

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ntfs

I've been tasked with updating a script that was created by someone else and I'm running into a wall. The script is used to gather NTFS permissions on a specific folder. The script currently outputs the Folder name, Group/User with access to that folder and It's permissions. I'd like to add a column showing if the account is enabled or disabled. For the life of me I can't figure how to get whether the user account is enabled or disabled added into the object. Here is the code i'm currently working with. I've tried to make some modifications to get the Enabled column filled but haven't been successful. Fairly new to powershell so hopefully that made sense!

Thank you

```
$FoldersToCheck = "P:\Companies\"

import-module activedirectory

Function ReportNTFS($p) {
    $temp = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Name -Path $p -Force -Depth 0
    $fullPath += ,$p
    ForEach ($x in $temp) {
        $fullPath += ,($p + $x)
    }
    $Output = @()
    $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'="Starting Folder: "+$p;'Group/User'='';'Enabled'='';'Permissions'=''}
    $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
    $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'='';'Group/User'='';'Enabled='='';'Permissions'=''}
    $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

    ForEach ($global:Folder in $fullPath) {
        $a,$b = $global:Folder -split $p,2,"simplematch"
#Write-Host "path: "  $b
       $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $global:Folder
       ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
           $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=".\"+$b;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}
           $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

           $thisShortID = $Access.IdentityReference -split "QUANTA\\"
           $groupList = $null
           try { $groupList = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $thisShortID[1] | select name  }
           catch { <# not a group #> }
           finally {
#Write-Host "*is group " 
               ForEach ($u in $groupList) {
                   $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=".\"+$b;'Group/User'=' --> '+$u.name;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}
                   $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
                }
           }

      try{
          $global:Enabled = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $thisShortID[1] | where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'} | get-aduser | select name
           foreach ($user in $global:enabled) { Get-ADUser -Identity $user | select Enabled }
           }
           catch{}
           finally{


                   ForEach ($e in $global:enabled) {
                   $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=".\"+$b;'Group/User'=' --> '+$u.name;'Enabled'=$e;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights}
                   $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
                   }
                   }

       }
       $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'='';'Group/User'='';'Enabled'='';'Permissions'=''}
       $Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
   }
    return ,$Output
}


ForEach ($f in $FoldersToCheck) {
    $reportArray = ReportNTFS($f)
}


    $reportArray 
}
```

Comment: Can you define what "haven't been successful" means? What *is* happening, and how is that different than what you want to happen?

Comment: When I currently run the script I can get everything except for the enabled/disabled status. I can't seem to figure out how to integrate Get-acl with Get-aduser so that the Enabled column lines up with the user accounts and produces the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

$enable = (Get-Aduser -filter 'SamAccountName -eq $Name').Enabled